# How to communicate with OBD II using bluetooth or wifi using iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, wifi, obd-ii

I like to create a simple application for iOS, which read data from car through ODB II Wifi/bluetooth device and display in iPhone screen. But i don't know where to start. Please somebody help me to achieve below results.

I have both Bluetooth and wifi dongle.

Step 1 : Pair the bluetooth or Wifi dongle and iPhone.

Step 2 : Read the details through dongles

Please refer any tutorial or sample code which i can understand easily. I want to understand the these process in-depth and want to code by myself. So please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is going to be really heavily dependent on the actual devices you've managed to find.  For the bluetooth, only BlueTooth LE will work, look for CoreBluetooth examples.  For Wi-fi you'll be using standard networking and/or http calls.

Comment: Did you finally solve this problem? Were you able to connect the iOS phone with an ODB2 device?

Comment: Did you got this to work? Can you share the knowledge? I am also working on a car app where I want to connect phone to the car dash device.

Answer (score 12):

As David mentioned, on iOS you can use WiFi OBD interface only. Standard Bluetooth (not BTLE) will not work. Bluetooth devices should be approved by Apple to be able to transfer data to/from iOS. AFAIK there is no such a OBD's.

Probably your OBD dongle is based on ELM327 chip. Good starting point is [this doc](http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf). Read it carefully. This is everything what you need. Interesting things starts at page 7.

On iOS you should open TCP connection with your OBD IP address(for example using `NSInputStream`, `NSOutputStream`), then configure OBD using AT commands. Rest is described in section "Talking to the Vehicle" (page 30) in ELM link. Enjoy reading :)

If you need more help- just ask.

Comment: If you are going to use ELM327 adapter, you can familiarize with Android way here: http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/how-guide-obdii-reader-app-development