# Communicate iOS with ODB 2

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I need to create an app read info from the ODB2 device installed in a car and show the data to the user but in a "funny" way. So I need to read the data and connect the phone to internet simultaneously.
I found this questions:[How to communicate with OBD II using bluetooth or wifi using iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738134/how-to-communicate-with-obd-ii-using-bluetooth-or-wifi-using-iphone) , but is from 2014, maybe now there is something.

I've been looking for an ODB2 device that can communicates with iOS via Bluetooth.
I found a couple of devices that can do the trick (like viecar or bluedriver), but using their own apps. Also, I found some devices that can talk with iOS via WiFi, but it would be annoying to be connecting your device to WiFi, then turning off WiFi and using mobile data again...

So my questions is:

Is it there any way to communicates via bluetooth with an ODB2 devices? Or better said, is it there any ODB2 device that can be used via Bluetooth with iOS?

Comment: Your device has to be approved (MFi which stands for Made For iPhone) to allow communication in Bluetooth, or to have one of the "allowed" profile (like Headset). Else, if you still want Bluetooth, it has to be Bluetooth Low-Energy. If that's not the case, you can't do it in iOS.

Comment: @Larme So, if the device is BLE is enough? That is my question, I neen an existing device that I can use to do this. Should I look up for an BLE ODB2 device?

Comment: Yes, if it's BLE, you should be able to do it.